# Create a window of custom class type in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qwindow

This is my first question here, so I'm trying to not sound stupid!

EXPLANATION:

I have a main window in Qt that has a button to create (sub-?) windows within the main window. This can be done as many times as the user wants, and each sub-window displays the same set of properties/items. I figured writing a class to hold all these properties would be a smart way to go about it (this would inherit the main window class), as each instance of the child window would automatically get the properties. I am using a slot to create each instance.

QUESTION:

Besides the desired properties, what do I add to the child window class to let Qt know that if I create an object of that type it should open a window?

For example, say I have implemented all the child window properties in a header file that looks something like this:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDialog>                        //Not sure about this

class ChildWindow : public ParentWindow

{
Q_OBJECT

public:
ChildWindow(QObject* parent);
~ChildWindow();

//Remaining properties like QSpinBox, Radio buttons etc

}
```

how then would I implement my slot? Like this?

```
void Parent::Slot()
{
ChildWindow* window;
window = new ChildWindow(this);
window->show()
}
```

My problem is that I don't see any code that indicates that `window` is a separate window. I can see that it is of type `ChildWindow`, but does just including `QDialog` give it the `show()` functionality?

EDIT:

I realise the first suggestion would be try and see if this works, but in the unlikely scenario that it works I wouldn't have learnt anything and I still wouldn't know why it worked, and if it didn't I would be back here asking this same question. I hope you guys understand.

EDIT 2:

```
error C2039: 'show' : is not a member of 'ChildWindow'
```

So I am guessing including `QDialog` did not do the trick

EDIT 3:

If I add this to the `ChildWindow` constructor

```
QDialog* child;
child = new QDialog;
child->show()
```

Do I have to do the same in the slot definition as well?

Comment: so how is your `ParentWindow` defined? In Qt you can display any `QWidget` afaik, so it does not need to be a `QDialog` or `QWindow` (but it makes sense if you want to show multiple windows to use one)

Comment: Is ParentWindow based on QMainWindow or QDialog?

Comment: @xander `ParentWindow` is defined as a `QDialog`, it is basically a blank canvas to display the child windows. It's constructor opens a generic widget with the "Create Child Window" button. But how do I create child windows of type `ChildWindow`? What do I add to the constructor of the `ChildWindow` class so that it knows to open a window?

Comment: @Jeroen3 QDialog

Comment: @EagerLearner well if your `ParentWindow` is a `QDialog` it should work with your code, just create an object and invoking the call method should work in theory.. maybe your ParentWindow is the problem so try using a default QDialog if that works better for you.

Comment: Please edit your question  to show the class definition for `ParentWindow`.

Comment: @G.M.    `ParentWindow` class constructor is defined just like the example in EDIT 3.

Comment: @xander I tried the example in EDIT 3, it didn't work. But I think taking the `->show()` from the slot definition should do the trick

Comment: @xander It worked, sort of. Now a new window does open up, but it is its own window, with its own icon in the taskbar. There is no indication that this window is a child of the original window. I wanted it to be a part of the parent window. Anyways, I will continue searching for an answer and report back here :D